# Firebase get 20 values but show 1 each user button click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to get from firebase 20 rows of 3 values in each (key, pergunta, answer):

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("question").child("art").orderByKey().limitToFirst(20);
```

But show them (key, pergunta, answer) only once at a time to user. Show row 1 (with key, pergunta, answer), then 2...

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot recipeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //get all 20 values
                lastKey = recipeSnapshot.getKey();
                pergunta = Objects.requireNonNull(recipeSnapshot.child("question").getValue()).toString();

                answer = Objects.requireNonNull(recipeSnapshot.child("answer").getValue()).toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, pergunta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
```

Why I'd like to get 20 rows and not just 1 at a time? Because user connect may fail, and getting 20 and show one at a time would give to user a more fluid experience.

I have a button and each time user click I'd like to get one toast from the next record...

```
public void next(View view) {
        // show to user key, pergunta, answer variables of 1 row (next click 2...)
    }
```

It it possible to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the `children` to `LinkedList(queue)`, then on click, `poll` the item from `LinkedList`, it will give you next item by removing it from list, once the list is empty, fetch next set if items.

First let's a data class to hold three fields you have

```
data class Recipe(val key:String, val pergunta: String, val answer: String)
```

Then we can store data using above format

```
LinkedList<Recipe> queue = new LinkedList<>();
for (DataSnapshot recipeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //get all 20 values
    lastKey = recipeSnapshot.getKey();
    queue.add(Recipe(recipeSnapshot.getKey(), Objects.requireNonNull(recipeSnapshot.child("question").getValue()).toString(),Objects.requireNonNull(recipeSnapshot.child("answer").getValue()).toString()));
}
```

Then you can just `poll` and display as `Toast`

```
public void onClick(view: View){
   if(!queue.isEmpty()){
       val recipe = queue.poll()
      //now you can also access key and answer using recipe.key and recipe.answer
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, recipe.pergunta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else
      //fetch next items
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but not help me because in each row I have 3 fields (key, pergunta, answer) that I'd like to store, not just 1.

Comment: I have updated answer as per your requirment